# Swift 3 | JSON Value of optional type '[String : Any] not unwrapped, did mean to use '!' or '?'?

Tags: json, swift

I'm currently learning Swift, and right now I'm learning about how to serialize / deserialize JSON objects, however I've come across an issue, in which I cannot get around! I'm receiving the error mentioned in the title, and I've tried everything, and still receive the error! Can someone please point me in the right direction as to how to resolve this error?

I believe that somewhere in my code a value is not getting unwrapped properly, however I can't pinpoint which value is causing the issue. The error highlights this line of code: if let Users = json["User"] as? [String: Any]

Using '!' instead of '?' in the json["User"] line of code, as well as the code above it, still causes the error to be received.

I've run out of ideas, and don't know what else to try.

Code:

```
let requestURL: URL = URL(string:   
    "url")!
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) 
-> Void in

    let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, 
        options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]

    if let Users = json["User"] as? [String: Any] {

}
```

JSON:

```
{  
   "User":[  
      {  
         "Coin":"4",
         "Email":"email@blank.com",
         "NumberBusinesses":"2",
         "NumberBusinessesSold":"4"
      },
      {  
         "Coin":"12",
         "Email":"email2@blank.com",
         "NumberBusinesses":"3",
         "NumberBusinessesSold":"6"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: In your last line, try `json?["User"]` instead of `json["User"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json` is optional (since you are using `as?`).

The best solution is to conditionally unwrap it:

```
if let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)) as? [String: Any] {
    if let Users = dict["User"] as? [String: Any] {
    }
}
```

Note, you should also be safely unwrapping `data`. If the data can't be obtained, using `data!` will crash your app.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, much appreciated. I just tried your solution, however I'm still receiving the error. Is it possible that the code above the json step is somehow responsible for the error?

Comment: @JaredHart I updated the answer to solve the problem.

Comment: thanks for the help, your solution resolves the error, however this line of code is not called "if let Users = dict["User"] as? [String: Any]. Does that mean that "if let json" code is returning nill?

Comment: Yes. This means either the call to `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` is throwing an error or the resulting object isn't really a dictionary with String keys. You should probably split the code up and use `try` inside a `do/catch` instead of `try?`. Then you can print any error.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much for the help, and thanks ebby94 for your help as well!

Answer (score 1):

The try statement here returns nil if the casting fails, as @rmaddy mentioned the conditional binding should prevent the json from being nil. But after trying it out the type of json is `[String:Any]?` even after the conditional binding which is the reason it was throwing that error.

But when I tried enclosing it in a `do..catch` block instead of optional `try` statement poof the error was gone. It's a bit confusing why the value of json is optional even after the conditional binding, but I'm convinced the optional try statement is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is resolved, thanks to ebby94! (also a thank you to rmaddy for helping!)

ebby94 advised to change this code: json["User"] as? [String: Any] to json?["User"] as? [String: Any]

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary using the code in my answer. Using `if let json = ...` eliminates the need to add the `?` after references to `json`.

Comment: Hmm would that mean there is a different underline issue occurring, if ebby94's solution is causing the app to build successfully, even with your solution still implemented?

Comment: @rmaddy I believe json["User"] produces an optional, since the key may or may not be present. But what if the value of json is nil? `nil["user"]` doesn't make much sense I believe. So I guess that's the reason we need to specify it as optional.

Comment: @ebby94 But `json` can't be `nil` on the `json["User"]` line using the code in my answer. That's the whole point of using `if let`.

Comment: @rmaddy oops, I missed that conditional binding there. But what about the question mark near `try`? What does the mean? :s

Comment: @ebby94 `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` can throw an error. Using `try?` means to "return nil if there is an error". So the right side of that `=` statement can result in `nil` if `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` throws an error or if it can't be cast (due to the `as?`).

Comment: @rmaddy I tried out your solution and it wasn't working. Please check my answer.

Comment: @ebby94 And see mine. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The following is deprecated

```
.allowFragments
```

instead use

```
.fragmentsAllowed
```

If you're fetching **JSON** it should return an **array** or **dictionary** already. So perhaps you can replace

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]

if let Users = json["User"] as? [String: Any]
```

with something like the following

```
let jsonDictionary try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data!, options: .fragmentsAllowed)
let Users = jsonDictionary["User"] as? NSMutableDictionary
```